# MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter & Serialization

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Based on the below guide
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converts the Greeting Object to JSON. Question is, why isn't Greeting Object implementing Serializable? Is it a miss in the guide or not required?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `Serializable` is necessary for native Java serialization.

JSON marshalling with Jackson doesn't need it.